# Need help on simple PHP loop to run on class objects

Tags: php, class, loops, object

I am looking for a way to make this foreach loop run on the UserData objects.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

class UserData{
    public $FName;
    public $LName;
    public $IP;
}

$user001 = new UserData();
$user002 = new UserData();
$user003 = new UserData();

$user001->FName = 'Erez';
$user001->LName = 'T';
$user001->IP = '192.168.0.1';


$user002->FName = 'Netali';
$user002->LName = 'Goz';
$user002->IP = '192.168.0.2';

$user003->FName = 'Charley';
$user003->LName = 'Abu Ben David';
$user003->IP = '192.168.0.3';
```

So up to here the class has the attributes picked up by the new objects above.

Now from this part below I'm using the `get_object_vars` to retrieve the `UserData` but I have no idea how to run it dynamically.

Can you help me with this in the shortest code possible with the most basic code?
(a for loop would be great!)

```
$vars = get_object_vars('UserData');
print_r($vars);
echo '<hr>';

foreach ($vars as $OP =>$OPVal){
    echo $OP .' is '.$OPVal.'<br>';
}
```

You can disregard the print_r and echo's.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can loop with this methode

```
for($x=1;$x<4;$x++){
    $vars = get_object_vars(${'user00'.$x});
    print_r($vars);
    echo '<hr>';
    foreach ($vars as $OP =>$OPVal){
        echo $OP .' is '.$OPVal.'<br>';
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

but, you better learn OOP concept first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making individual instances of the object, create an array of objects, and add as many as you need.
You can also add a constructor for the class, to instantiate easier.

Example:

```
class UserData{
    public $FName;
    public $LName;
    public $IP;

    public function __construct($fname,$lname,$ip){
        $this->FName = $fname;
        $this->LName = $lname;
        $this->IP = $ip;
    }
}

//store your data in some arrays
$firstNames = array('Erez','Netali','Charley');
$lastNames = array('T','Goz','Abu Ben David');
$ips = array('192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2','192.168.0.3');

$users = array();
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    // instantiate each new object using data from the above arrays
    $users[] = new UserData($firstNames[$i],$lastNames[$i],$ips[$i]);
    // or use your method 

    /*
    $users[] = new UserData('Netali','Goz','192.168.0.2')
    */
}

// now iterate over your array of UserData objects and print their properties
foreach ($users as $user){
    print $user->FName . ", " . $user->LName . ", " . $user->IP . PHP_EOL;
}
// outputs
Erez, T, 192.168.0.1
Netali, Goz, 192.168.0.2
Charley, Abu Ben David, 192.168.0.3
```